# Inverse limit of countable (or even finite) sets

Tags: general-topology

Sorry if this is kind of a stupid question. I am trying to wrap my head around inverse limits. Question : can an inverse limit of countable sets be uncountable ? Typically something like a Cantor set.

If yes could you please include an example, and if no an argument ?

Comment: Isn't the inverse limit of $\Bbb Z/5^n\Bbb Z$, the $5$-adic integers, uncountable?

Comment: isn't this the prüfer group ? I thought this was countable

Comment: oh I think you're right. and this typically does look like a Cantor set, doesn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.

Comment: thank you ! I feel somewhat reassured now (I still have some reading and thinking to do!)

Comment: Yeah, the Prüfer group is the direct limit of $\mathbb Z/5^n\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a product $F^\mathbb{N}$ of spaces, then this product is the limit of an inverse system: let $X_n = F^n$ for all $n$, and the connecting functions $f_{n,m}: X_n \rightarrow X_m$, for $m \le n$ are just the projections onto the first $m$ coordinates.

Then the limit of the inverse sequence we get this way is just $F^\mathbb{N}$. And the latter space is uncountable (for $F$ finite, at least size 2, and say discrete, this is a Cantor set). And all $X_n$ are finite spaces in that case.

So yes: a limit of an inverse system of finite spaces can be uncountable.

Comment: right. thanks for taking the time to answer !